# Закрытая программа остаётся в процессах

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

После сборки скрипта в exe с помощью pyinstaller я закрываю получившуюся программу, но она остаётся в процессах и её можно закрыть уже через диспетчер задач.

> pyinstaller -F -w -i=D:/icon.ico D:/keywords_and_sites.py

Comment: покажите как вы обрабатывете выход

Comment: pyinstaller -F -w -i=D:/icon.ico D:/keywords_and_sites.py

Comment: Я про код который отрабатывется внутри прргаммы при закрытии.

Comment: Код достаточно объёмный. Это парсер, в котором  есть строка threading.Thread(target=progress).start(), которая способствует работе прогрессбара. Я думаю, что она может мешать полноценному закрытию программы

Comment: Ну так вот напишите минимальный пример, когда проблема воспроизводится. Скорее всего либо обратно не вызываете `join()`, либо в самой ветке нет условия выхода. Опять же не забывайте про флаг `daemon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментариям вам может помочь эта строка:
`threading.Thread(target=progress, daemon=True).start()`